# virt-manager printing to from windows 7 guest to Ubuntu host network printer

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I have just switched my vm from vmware to virt-manager.

I can't find any information on how to configure or print from my guest os (windows 7) to my printer HP printer that is on my network.

I have tried to discover the printer from the vm and find nothing.  I can access the internet from the vm.  I do not seem to be able to ping the printer.
I also don't seem to be able to find information on how to solve this problem.

My host OS is Ubuntu 23.10 and I can print from the host to the network printer.  I have the network set up as NAT.

thank you